# Android Library Compiles Against JDK 8

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, android-sdk-tools

I use nexus repository to upload my local/private libraries into, and the last week I updated the Android library to target the latest SDK, latest Gradle, and latest Support Libraries, now when I try to upload the library the maven repository the AAR file (classes) gets compiled with Java 8 instead of 6 or 7 (Major Version 52, and previously was 50/51).

also if I try to build the library using (`./gradlew build`) and extract the generated AAR file then check the classes Java major version it will be 52 (JDK8).

I tried many things to solve it with no luck (ex. forcing to use JDK 7 on build command, source and target set to 7 and didn't work)

any hint would help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gladly I got the answer from another place from a Google developer: they don't support desugaring for libraries right now, and it will happen on the application dexing level (apk).